# Kotlin code refactoring

Tags: kotlin

I have a function which is checking if there are a searching conditions or not.

```
var currentStatus = MutableLiveData<List<Int>>()

private var sellerIds: List<Int>? = null
private var subSellerIds: List<Int>? = null
private var partnerIds: List<Int>? = null
private var productTypeIds: List<Int>? = null
private var brunchIds: List<Int>? = null
private var contractDateFrom: String? = null
private var contractDateTo: String? = null
private var completeDateFrom: String? = null
private var completeDateTo: String? = null

private var totalStatusCnt: Int = 10

val isSearching = ObservableField<Boolean>(false)

private fun checkIfSearchConditions() {
    if (currentStatus.value != null && currentStatus.value!!.isNotEmpty() &&
            currentStatus.value?.size != totalStatusCnt) {
        isSearching.set(true)
    } else if (keyword != null && keyword!!.isNotEmpty()) {
        isSearching.set(true)
    } else if (sellerIds != null && sellerIds!!.isNotEmpty()) {
        isSearching.set(true)
    } else if (subSellerIds != null && subSellerIds!!.isNotEmpty()) {
        isSearching.set(true)
    } else if (partnerIds != null && partnerIds!!.isNotEmpty()) {
        isSearching.set(true)
    } else if (productTypeIds != null && productTypeIds!!.isNotEmpty()) {
        isSearching.set(true)
    } else if (brunchIds != null && brunchIds!!.isNotEmpty()) {
        isSearching.set(true)
    } else if (contractDateFrom != null && contractDateFrom!!.isNotEmpty()) {
        isSearching.set(true)
    } else if (contractDateTo != null && contractDateTo!!.isNotEmpty()) {
        isSearching.set(true)
    } else if (completeDateFrom != null && completeDateFrom!!.isNotEmpty()) {
        isSearching.set(true)
    } else if (completeDateTo != null && completeDateTo!!.isNotEmpty()) {
        isSearching.set(true)
    } else {
        isSearching.set(false)
    }
}
```

And the **checkIfSearchConditions** method looks so dirty, so I want to refactor the method to make it clear.

and I tried to make an empty checking method like this,

```
private fun checkIfNotEmpty(field: Any?): Boolean {
    return field != null && field!!.isNotEmpty() // isNotEmpty is not unsolved reference
}
```

But the filed type could be List? or String?, so getting 
'isNotEmpty is not unsolved reference' error.

How can I refactor the method to make clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make two separate overloaded methods for `List<*>?` and `String?`:

```
private fun checkIfNotEmpty(field: String?): Boolean {
    return field != null && field.isNotEmpty()
}
private fun checkIfNotEmpty(field: List<*>?): Boolean {
    return field != null && field.isNotEmpty()
}
```

Note that you don't need `!!` in `field!!.isNotEmpty()` in these methods: because it isn't a `var`, after checking it doesn't equal `null` Kotlin knows it can't change to become one.

Another, IMO worse approach, would be to keep `Any?` as parameter type and check whether you have `List` or `String` at runtime:

```
private fun checkIfNotEmpty(field: Any?): Boolean {
    return when(field) {
        null -> false
        is List<*> -> field.isNotEmpty()
        is String -> field.isNotEmpty()
        else -> false
    }
}
```

Additionally, all the `else if` branches with same body can be combined using `||` instead:

```
if ((checkIfNotEmpty(currentStatus) &&
        currentStatus?.value?.size != totalStatusCnt) ||
    checkIfNotEmpty(keyword) ||
    checkIfNotEmpty(sellerIds) || ...
) {
    isSearching.set(true)
} else {
    isSearching.set(false)
}
```

which can be improved even more to

```
val isSearchingValue = (checkIfNotEmpty(currentStatus) &&
        currentStatus?.value?.size != totalStatusCnt) ||
    checkIfNotEmpty(keyword) ||
    checkIfNotEmpty(sellerIds) || ...
isSearching.set(isSearchingValue)
```

Comment: Why not use `String?.isNullorEmpty()` from the stdlib? https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/is-null-or-empty.html

And I'd create extension functions instead of regular functions.

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin stdlib contains functions

```
public inline fun CharSequence?.isNullOrEmpty(): Boolean = this == null || this.length == 0
public inline fun CharSequence?.isNullOrBlank(): Boolean = this == null || this.isBlank()
```

You may define similar fun for `Collection?`